# Using get/set asp.net c# theres too many properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, set

I am use to creating a properties class where I would include all my fields and have to write all the get/set properties then have another Database class where i would make all my database calls.

```
Properties Class
    private int _intCard
    public int IntCard
    {
        set { _intcard = value;}
    }
Constructor here
```

Right now this does not feel like the right approach as I have over 120 properties that I will be dealing with and seems really time consuming to have to write each one of those properties out. I will need to add validation to some of the properties is my reason for choosing this way, i could validate it in the set method. Can anyone suggest an alternative way that I could look into to complete the same result.

```
********************---------------*******************
```

So giving the comments I understand my design is flawed that is what I figured coming into this question. I have an idea on how to fix this but do not know if it is the correct way to approach this. I searched for Object Design Principles and read up on that but will need more time to grasp what it is teaching me. For now I would like to know if this approach is the correct way

I am keeping track of applicants name,address,phone,faxnumber,cellphone,altphone,altaddress, same for spouse, and then children, references, company information.....and so on

I am not going to lie I do not understand abstract classes yet in order to implement this if that is the approach I should take I will take more time to learn that but for now was hoping this would be suitable.

Property classes would be as followed
applicant.cs, applicantspouse.cs, applicantcontactinfo.cs, appreferences.cs......

Is this along the lines of what I should be doing?

Thanks again

Comment: why not use auto properties instead..? if you are not doing anything unique with the properties

Comment: @DJKRAZE It's because he wants to perform validation in the setter. However, I would suggest that validation could be performed using auto-properties with data annotations (although I also agree with Brian that 120 properties seems like a lot in a single class!)

Comment: @DJKRAZE `Class.IntCard.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.`

Comment: If you don't want to validate then you can simply write public int intcard{get;set;}

Comment: @krshekhar Yes, but since he *explicitly stated* that he wants to validate it in the set method, that's not very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the comments it looks like you need at least two classes Person, Address something like:

```
public class Person 
{
  Guid Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  // ad infinitum the truely unique things that relate to an Individual

  Address BusinessAddress {get; set;}
  Address HomeAddress {get; set;}
  Person Spouse {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
  Guid Id {get; set;}
  Line1 {get; set;}
  // ad infinitum all the truly unique things that relate to an address
}
```

The above is essentially pseudo-code and shouldn't be read as "This is exactly how to do it", I haven't for instance stated whether the properties are private/public/protected or indeed provided a constructor.

But it does show how you can use other classes as properties and in the case of "Spouse" create quite rich and deep object Hierarchies (Spouse could contain addresses and potentially another spouse - circular reference ahoy!) which can be populated and used to make code more readable and separate out the responsibility of the code to encapsulate a "concept/entity/domain" into a single unit who's job it is to be "that specific thing". Probably worth looking at OOP concepts like encapsulation, inheritance and so on  (basically the four tenets of OO) here to get a feel for what an object should represent, this link has a brief intro and should help you in deciding how to break out the classes and construct more useful objects.

http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/19/4-major-principles-of-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 5):

I can't help thinking your object modelling isn't right here. If you have a class with 120 properties then you've not divided up that object into separate roles/responsibilities etc. I would look at increasing (dramatically) the number of classes you're creating, and that way your solution becomes more manageable.

That won't reduce the number of properties that you have to handle. It may be worth considering immutable objects (do you need to set these properties beyond during construction?), and/or the use of the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern to aid construction.

Finally, do you need to *expose* these properties ? A key part of OO is *telling objects to do things for you*, rather than getting their contents and doing things for them. If you can tell an object to do something for you, you quite likely don't need to expose their (internal) fields.

Comment: +1  `If you have a class with 120 properties then you've not divided up that object into separate roles/responsibilities etc.` I completely agree with you

Comment: Thanks for the response this is going to be an application that is going to record that individuals personal information. Such as name,address,phone,alternatephone,business name spouse name, address,phone...and so on seems like all these fields would be part of one class. Can you suggest small example of what you mean by split them up.

Comment: Are you saying even though its one application with one Submit button I would create multiple property classes such as primaryapplicant.cs, spouseapplicant.cs, businessinfo.cs, references.cs...

Answer (score 0):

In modern c# versions there's a super compact sintax for properties:

```
public class Properties {
    public int IntCard { get; set; }
}
```

Here c# handles the private variable for you, this way you can avoid a lot of keystrokes. For validation you can use **Data Annotations**. More info [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks will look into the Data Annotations seems like I need to split up my properties so far from the responses

Comment: yes, of course, a single object with sooo many properties almost always points to a problem on initial design, but you should arrange that looking at your schema from a global point of view. good luck!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this does not address your design issues. If your database is on sql-server, to avoid typing you could use a query like this (please modify for your requirement) to get the property list with datatypes and then copy and paste the results. [SQL SERVER DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b317/1)

```
SELECT  'public ' + CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN 'smallint' THEN 'short' 
                WHEN 'bit' THEN 'bool'
                WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN 'System.DateTime'
                WHEN 'datetime' THEN 'System.DateTime'
                WHEN 'date' THEN 'System.DateTime'
                WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'System.Guid'
                WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'string'
                WHEN 'int' THEN 'int' 
                WHEN 'numeric' THEN 'decimal'
                ELSE DATA_TYPE END 
          + CASE IS_NULLABLE  WHEN 'NO' THEN '' ELSE '?' END
          + ' ' + COLUMN_NAME 
          + ' { get; set; }' AS def
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
ORDER BY IS_NULLABLE, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @brian-agnew that if you have that many properties in 1 class then you probably need to do some refactoring as you almost certainly do not have enough separation of concerns.

However even after some refactoring, you will still have the properties, so it would be worth looking at the data validation attributes. For example, here is a walk though of using them with MVC: [http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs). You could then use [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) properties:

```
public int IntCard { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

Based on your edit, you look like you are on the right lines. You should be breaking the properties down into specific items, for example:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo ContactInformation { get; set; }
    }

public class Applicant : Person
    {
        public Person Spouse { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
        public List<Reference> References { get; set; }
    }

public class ContactInfo
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
        public Address AlternativeAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

So the key points for you here are that

1. the class are broken down into manageable, reusable chunks
2. Data Annotations (Required & DataType in the ContactInfo class) are used to validate properties
3. The properties no longer need explicit private variables

P.S. A bit more info about data annotations: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)